# JQuery - checkboxes dont't turn on

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

I'm having a problem with jquery.

I have a checkbox with ID "#checkAll" and checkboxes with class "checkboxes".
I'd like to turn all checkboxes on when the checkbox with ID "checkAll" is checked,
and I'd like to turn all checkboxes off when the checkbox with ID "checkAll" is checked off.

But, What's having now is that when I first click the checkbox(#checkAll), all other checkboxes are turned on and when I first turn the ckeckbox(#checkAll), all other checkboxs are turned off as well.

But, when I try to click the checkbox(#checkAll) in the second time, all other checkboxes are not turned on.

I don't know why this happens.

Please help me out!

This is my javascript handling events.

```
ADMIN.event = (function() {

    function _init(){

        $(function(){

            var checkAll = $('#checkAll'),
                checkboxes = $('.checkboxes');

            checkAll.click(function(){
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
                } else {
                    checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
                }
            })

        });

    }


    _init();


}());
```

This is my view file in php.

```
<table class="fullTable">
    <tr class="listTableTr">
        <th class="listTableTh tinyTh"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkAll" /></th>
        <th id="articleTitleTh" class="listTableTh">title</th>

    </tr>

    <?php foreach($postData as $post): ?>

        <td class="listTableTd"><input type="checkbox"  name="" class="checkboxes" /></td>
        <td class="listTableTd"><a href="<?php echo 'index.php?r=admin/post/edit&post='.$post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['title'];?></a></td>

    <?php endforeach; ?>                        

</table>
```

Comment: If you are using `jQuery 1.6+`, use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr`.

Comment: yes, I've just downloaded the latest Jquery. It should be Jquery 1.6+.

Comment: I see, I'd try prop()!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `.prop()` like

```
checkAll.click(function(){
    checkboxes.prop('checked',this.checked); 
});
```

And its better to use even with `.on()` like

```
checkAll.on('click' , function(){
    checkboxes.prop('checked',this.checked); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! I'm using Jquery 1.10.2.

I'll look into prop()and on().

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
    $('#checkAll').on('click',function(){
        if($("#checkAll").is(':checked')) {
            $('.checkboxes').attr('checked',true);
        } else {
            $('.checkboxes').attr('checked',false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/adF3X/)**
Try this

```
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
    $(".checkboxes").prop("checked","checked");
    else
         $(".checkboxes").prop("checked",false);
});
```